# if else does not work

Tags: php

i have problem with if else statement in zend framework

```
<?php if(count($this->result) > 0) {
echo "not found";
}
else{ 
echo "advertise here";
}
?>
```

i would like to hide ads if there is no result, somehow, it does not work, please help

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I've understood the question correctly. But try

```
<?php 
 if(count($this->result) > 0) {
  echo "advertise here";
 }else{ 
  // do nothing..effectively hiding.
 }
?>
```

You can also get rid of the else part completely.

Comment: i believe it's the same with my code :p, i finally found the problem, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Your if else statement seems to be correct. 
Did you try to check the content of your variable with a

```
var_dump($this->result)
```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, i am missed the getItems, it works now with <?php if(count($this->result->getItems()) > 0) {, finally :p